# how to copy the console output into a file in java?

Tags: java, android

```
package prgms;

import java.io.BufferedReader;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;

import java.io.IOException;

import java.io.InputStreamReader;

class new_experi {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("C://Users//sihi//Desktop//output.txt"));
        try

        {
            String inputLine = null;
            do {
                inputLine = in.readLine();
                out.write(inputLine);
                out.newLine();
            } while (!inputLine.equalsIgnoreCase("eof"));
            System.out.print("Write Successful");
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            System.out.println("Error during reading/writing");
        } finally {
            out.close();
            in.close();
        }

    }

}
```

i am getting output but the last line i.e **"write successfully**" is not copied to the file.

Comment: You could try using output redirection symbol ">" on the terminal. For (ex: run using the command $java MyApp > OutputFile.txt) All your stdout text will be saved into the OutputFile.txt without changing anything in your source.

Comment: use Out.write(); as you have already configured BufferWriter to write to a file

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
System.out.print("Write Successful");
```

Write

```
out.write("Write Successful");
```

And if you are trying to log, you can use [**log4j**](http://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-hello-world-example/).

Answer (score 0):

System.out.print("")  will output into Console,u should use out.write("") instead.